# Корректно ли: "До 15 раз больше"

Tags: лексика

Добрый день!
Дело чести копирайтера.

Знаю, что некорректно, но не могу найти правило использование "до" в данном случае (чувствую, что после него должна быть используемая самостоятельно форма максимального значения):

Покупайте сегодня и ПОЛУЧАЙТЕ ДО 15 РАЗ БОЛЬШЕ БОНУСОВ.

Права ли я, что некорректно?
Какие есть правила, разъяснения в словарях/справочниках?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю, как насчет того, чтобы в писаных правилах. На каждую некорректность не придумаешь отдельного правила. Тут штука в том, что, если надо искать правила, то не на "до", а на *"в N раз больше"*. Есть выражение "в столько-то раз больше", но оно требует предлога "в". А вот без этого предлога с "раз больше" не получается.

Надо бы сказать *"в до пятнадцати раз больше"* - это было бы разумно и в каком-то смысле правильно. Но грамматика против такого совместного использования предлогов.

Но поскольку в русском нет разумного эквивалента для этой кальки с английского, то, боюсь, бороться с таким использованием бесполезно. Рано или поздно придется признать, что такая конструкция необходима языку.

Возможно, кто-то попонятнее объяснит.

Comment: >> *Рано или поздно придется признать, что такая конструкция необходима языку.* Еще бы. Ведь если в рекламе сказать, что новое средство от тараканов **в 10 раз** лучше прежнего, то юристы конкурентов могут и придраться. Миллионными штрафами грозит! А если **ДО 10 раз лучше** – то все шито-крыто, не подкопаешься. В 1,25 раза – это тоже укладывается в "до 10". А цифра-то 10 озвучена, и пипл хавает.

Comment: @Niemand, меня эта сторона не слишком забавляет. Но если уж вам так хочется за это поговорить... Во-первых, в России такие законы (не только о рекламе) и такие конкуренты, что подобного рода иски бесперспективны. Все упрется в то, что истец - а не ответчик, как во всем цивилизованном мире -   вынужден будет доказывать методику проверки цифры. А во-вторых, интересен чисто лингвистический момент. Обходились же как-то без этого уродца еще лет тридцать-сорок назад. А нужда в подобных формулировках возникает далеко не только у рекламщиков, но у всех, например, кто  имел дело с любыми расчетами.

Comment: Так что я думаю, тут дело не в исках, а в механическом перенесении английской конструкции "up to N times". Но фокус в том, что грамматически она не требует никакого "больше" и в абсолютном большинстве случаев в таком виде и используется.

Comment: >> *Обходились же как-то без этого уродца еще лет тридцать-сорок назад. А нужда в подобных формулировках возникает далеко не только у рекламщиков, но у всех, например, кто имел дело с любыми расчетами.* Именно и только у рекламщиков! За очень-очень малым исключением, в чисто технических текстах... В этом все и дело.

Comment: *Именно и только у рекламщиков!* - вы знаете всех, у кого в чем нужда?  *В этом все и дело* - в том, что решаете за всех?

Comment: В данном случае именно у рекламщиков, конечно) нельзя написать в 20 раз больше, потому что это или не за все товары, или при выполнении определённых условий. Иначе - ФАС, закон о недобросовестной рекламе и защита прав потребителей. Это и есть причина поиска вменяемой формулировки.

Comment: Интересный разговор. Никак не могу согласиться, что вопрос касается только рекламщиков. Они этим грешат больше других - по вполне понятным причинам. Но чтобы это только им разрешалось (или наоборот запрещалось, так и не понял) - это что-то ирреальное. Нет, правила одни на всех. И нужда в таком обороте, конечно, возникает совсем не только в рекламе.

Answer (score 1):

Ну если дело чести...

Как насчёт: 
"Покупайте сегодня и получайте до 15 бонусов вместо одного" ?

Тоже не идеально, но менее коряво, и осталось "до" для юридических троллей.

В нерекламных целях - есть такое слово коэффициент. Например, "коэффициент бонусности *может достигать* 15,00"

Answer (score 1):

А если так: ПОЛУЧАЙТЕ В НЕСКОЛЬКО (ДО 15) РАЗ БОЛЬШЕ БОНУСОВ? Как вам?